# NotificationObject & UnaryMember

Tags: .net, silverlight, mvvm, prism, inotifypropertychanged

I've seen numerous implementations of the **INotifyPropertyChanged** ([Automatically INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527602/automatically-inotifypropertychanged)) that have support for the **UnaryExpression** in addition to the **MemberExpression**.  Examples of the **UnaryExpression** include uses of unary operators within the expression such as,

```
RiasePropertyChanged(() => !MyPropertyName);
```

Is there reason enough to warrant its inclusion in the property name extraction?  I had supposed the support for the **UnaryExpression** is because you could extract the **MemberExpression** from this.

Does the community have any pro/cons related this this implementation as it differs from the Prism **NotificationObject**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only seen this in situations where someone wanted to support a wide variety of ways to refer to the member. Limiting it to UnaryExpression limits you slightly.

It doesn't really matter... adding support for both will be primarily a performance concern, but it will likely not make much difference in the end. I'd say support both just so you don't risk having the usage be more of a leaky abstraction than it already is.

Here's what we use:

```
public void OnPropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)
{
    var lambda = (LambdaExpression)property;
    MemberExpression memberExpression;

    if ( lambda.Body is UnaryExpression )
    {
      var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
      memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
    }
    else
    {
      memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
    }
    OnPropertyChanged(memberExpression.Member.Name);
}
```