# CallerMemberName in an extension (INotifyPropertyChanged)

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I am currently implementing an Extension for the INotifiyPropertyChanged interface, you can read this:

[INotifyPropertyChanged - Event stays null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484581)

for furhter information.

Now I would like to extend this extension further so that I dont need to state the MemberExpression and when calling it from inside a set that the CallerMemberName Attribute does the rest.

So I have tried to do the following (based on the links provided in my last stackoverflow question):

```
public static void Notify(this PropertyChangedEventHandler EventHandler, object sender, 
[CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (EventHandler != null)
    {
        EventHandler(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This allows me to call the method like this:

```
this.PropertyChanged.Notify(this); //with CallerMemberName
this.PropertyChanged.Notify(this, "RandomProperty");
```

Now I would like to remove the neccessarity to always write the (this, ..) parameter and just call it like so:

```
this.PropertyChanged.Notify(); //with CallerMemberName
this.PropertyChanged.Notify("RandomProperty");
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, it *isn't* possible. You need 3 pieces of information:

- the event-handler instance (`this.PropertyChanged`, on the left)
- the event-name (`propertyName`, supplied by the compiler)
- the sender (`sender`)

`sender` cannot be inferred from any of the other information, and there is no compiler option to provide it. However, frankly, I would simply use an instance method instead:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if(handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Then the caller simply issues:

```
OnPropertyChanged(); // job done
```

You could of course have `OnPropertyChanged` call your static method, but that seems unnecessary.

In some ways it *feels* like we should be able to just pass in the `INotifyPropertyChanged` instance to use for both `sender` and to access the `PropertyChanged`, but of course we can't get the actual *delegate* from an `event` declaration.

Comment: To make the .Notify fool proof, do you know about a posibility to prevent this call "this.PropertyChanged.Notify("RandomProperty");" from getting successfully compiled? Because in this case the "RandomProperty" equals the sender and CallerMemberName does get autofilled and it "runs" but makes no sense.

Comment: To bad, it's not possible.