# Check if Hex string is correct in Converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a text box to input and show color Hex value.The binding is twoway to a color property of a parent.

Everything is working but, I need to make sure, in case I enter manually a Hex in the text box, and if this a not correct string, then use and display the current Hex value of the color, rather than trying to change it.

Here is what I tried but obviously it's not working, I'm a beginner and I have only a little experience with converter and WPF. If I write anything but not a valid Hex string, at the moment the textbox gets a red outline, but I wish that in this case, the Hex previous string reappears.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Color), typeof(String))]
public class ColorToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color colorValue = (Color)value;
        return ColorNames.GetColorName(colorValue);
    }
    public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ColorHexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var hexCode = System.Convert.ToString(value);

        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hexCode))
        //    return null;
        try
        {
            var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(hexCode);
            return color;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var hexCode = System.Convert.ToString(value);
        Regex myRegex = new Regex("^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$");
        bool isValid = false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hexCode))
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isValid = myRegex.IsMatch(hexCode);
        }

        try
        {
            return hexCode;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the C# class for the TextBox

```
public class ColorHex : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            BindingExpression bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, TextProperty);
            if (bindingExpression != null)
                bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
        }
    }
}
```

And its xaml in Generic.xaml

```
<local:ColorHex x:Name="PART_ColorHex" Style="{StaticResource ColorPickerTextBox}" Text="{Binding SelectedColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToHexConverter},  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ColorPicker}}}" />
```

Any idea ?

thank you

Comment: Please show your XAML as well.

Comment: Please define "not working". What's going wrong and where?

Comment: ok I added more infos

Answer (score 0):

A valid hex color has the form '`#nnn`' or `'#nnnnnn'`.
So, the `regex` for this case would be: `(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)`
NOw, you could add these lines of code:

```
var regex = @"(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)"
var match = Regex.Match(inputYouWantToCheck, regex,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (!match.Success)
    {
        // Color is not valid
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that and thanks for your answer but this is not exactly what I'm asking for. How would it be possible in case it doesn't match, to output the current color Hex value ? instead of trying to change it with a wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it differently, using property to validate the color:

```
public Color Color { get; set; } = Colors.Red;

public string ColorText
{
    get { return (new ColorConverter()).ConvertToString(Color); }
    set
    {
        Color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(value);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Bind to `ColorText`, it will throw in case it's wrong hex, and you can use `ExceptionValidationRule` to display it (as a red border):

```
<TextBox Text="{local:ExceptionBinding Path=ColorText}" />
```

where

```
public class ExceptionBinding : Binding
{
    public ExceptionBinding() : base()
    {
        ValidationRules.Add(new ExceptionValidationRule());
    }
}
```

As a bonus you can enter known colors as text, e.g. `"Red"`:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying this but OnPropertyChanged() need an argument no ?

Comment: Yes (it needs argument) and no (it's optional). You can use `CallerMemberNameAttribute` to automatically supply method name at compile time (property setter is method), see how `OnPropertyChanged` is implemented in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18485965/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

What if you did something where you add a label next to the textbox to show an example of what color has been entered. You would just need to change the label color change each time.